# YouTube Annotations via PHP Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, annotations, youtube-api

Is it possible to add annotations to a YouTube video using the PHP Zend framework and the YouTube API?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the YouTube API does not support this functionality. It is currently a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=558